# How to get uniqueID from firebase across several pages

Tags: javascript, firebase

my project is the survey with several pages. I want to upload answers of several pages into the same uniqueID. Now I can get uniqueID from a page js file, but how can I transport this uniqueID to other js files so I can upload the data to the same uniqueID.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reformulated to how have a variable value accessible through out varying pages and js files.

- My prefered way to do it - with lots of data - is a base page invisible to the user loading a "global script". This base page loads and unloads all other pages (including js and css files). Since the variable in your case the firebaseID is globally defined it works.
- If its not sensible data you can also put it to the LocalStorage (preferable encrypted) This would also help if a user wants to pause the survey and later on to finish it. (You have 5MB on mobile devices and 10 MB on desktop).

More details on solution one:
The easy part is to insert HTML into other HTML. I use server generated views so the base page gets HTML added and removed as needed.
The harder part is the page (view) specific loading of js.
In my use case the users can jump around via a navigation until they finally submit and finish. If you only allow sequential moving forward and no backward its easier. I actually mimic a restful behavior. Some building blocks in the base script include

```
// Some global vars
var statMsg = "";
var navTargetInitial= "app";
var navTarget;
var htmlDir = "app";    // directory of the html templates
var scriptDir = "js";   // directory of the user scripts

var routes = [
{
    navTarget: "main", 
    loadScript: true,
    navTitle: "Survey page 1",
    navMenutext: "Page 1"
}, {
    navTarget: "app",  
    loadScript: true,
    navTitle: "Survey page 2",
    navMenutext: "Page 2"
}, 
....
];

// Then docReady beside other stuff
function docReady() {
// other stuff
nav2Page(navTarget);
}

// here we handover data, put relevant things to sessionStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
// Do stuff
};

 // here we cleanup
window.onunload = function () {
    // cleanup
};
```

The crucial part is loading the new js after the html is in DOM so an essential part is an eventhandler on the event DOM loaded

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
 loadJScript(navScript, function(response, status, xhr ){// error handling }
```

The rest is ajax, error handling, reaction to clicks on going back/ forward in the page history and reacting accordingly to it.
Hope this helps

Comment: can you explain " My prefered way to do it " more?